# Creating a scroll pin animation that expands accordions with framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

[image: accordion]

I want to reveal next/prev expandable based on scroll position and scrolling up/down. How would i approach it?

I tried to track their progress and check if one of the expandables is in center, `scrollYProgress` being around 0.5, but the screen and scroll position shifts a litle bit when i expand one accortion and close another.

This causes flickery animation and most of the time just skips in between accordions. If #2 is expanded, i scroll a bit down, #5 gets selected. So doesnt seem like a solution to the problem.

```
function Accortion(props: { idx: number; label: string }) {
   const headingRef = useRef(null)
   const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({ target: headingRef })

   useMotionValueEvent(scrollYProgress, 'change', latest => {
      if (latest > 0.49 && latest < 0.51) {
         approachesSelection.setState({ idx: props.idx })
      }
   })

   // ...
```

Edit: following adsy's comment makes it work, to a good extend. But i notice there the skipping of one accordion still takes place.

[Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/test-nextjs-13-tailwind-forked-13oy2z?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A1%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D&file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx)

Comment: Try using the node that includes the text as the thing to check against center, rather than the actual whole accordian element because this will be stable. It would also help alot for you to post the code.

Comment: ah i see, lemme try out with the text node and also post the code in a bit

Comment: @adsy Following your advice makes it work. ty. But i still couldnt make it snappy and i assume it to reveal the collapsable when its on center, idk some of the reveals happen when the element is further down or top of the screen

Comment: It could be because when the first one opens, the second one (including the title) is pushed down and may then be pushed beyond the centerline. I think one way to do this would be to calculate what the centerline would be of the title when all the ones above are open. You can do this if you always render the body of the accordian but make it invisible using `visbility :hidden`. Because then you could measure what the centerline would be using a bit of maths for when they are open, and use that value as the "corrected center" for each accordian.

Comment: Obviously that is vastly more complex. I can try and take a look on your codesandbox, but will be a bit later

Comment: Another simpler way of doing it might be to make it so the accordians do not open if another accordian in the process of opening. Because then if the accordian pushes the next one down past the centerline, the bottom would stay closed instead of opening prematurely.

Comment: locking one element when another one is opening might not work, becase users can scroll up and down fast and i want to create the smooth experience. i'll try to get my head around the math, hmm..

Comment: Actually, I think i might need a better description of intended behaviour. It seems ok with the change to use the header. What you are seeing is really an illusion -- the header of the accordian is opened only when its in the center, but because that cause the previous one to collapse, its now higher up. Do you see what I mean? I think it can be countered by offsetting by adding on the open height of the previous accordian to the trigger point. Quite tricky.

Comment: Im gonna have a go at it and get back to you

Comment: @adsy Ah i see, i just realized, there is indeed an illusion as you've said. But the some elements still doesnt open when i scroll fast, or click on the scrollbar to avoid scrolling and jump to bottom/top. 

Intended behaviour is is just how described, just without incosistencies, like skipping, or not opening when it is in the center. Should i make the radius bigger. Like 0.4 to 0.6

Comment: Im going to post an answer with corrected solution for the illusion problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cs from "classnames";
import {
  domAnimation,
  LazyMotion,
  m,
  useMotionValueEvent,
  useScroll,
} from "framer-motion";
import { useRef, forwardRef, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { create } from "zustand";

const selection = create<{ idx: number }>(() => ({
  idx: 0,
}));

const Accortion = forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  { idx: number; label: string; prevAccordianHeight: number | null }
>((props, ref) => {
  const headingRef = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement | null>(null);
  const { scrollY } = useScroll({ target: headingRef });

  useMotionValueEvent(scrollY, "change", (latest) => {
    if (props.idx === 1) {
      console.log(
        latest - headingRef.current!.offsetTop,
        window.innerHeight / 2
      );
    }

    const pixelsFromTopOfWindow = latest - headingRef.current!.offsetTop;

    if (
      pixelsFromTopOfWindow + (props.prevAccordianHeight ?? 0) >=
      -(window.innerHeight / 2)
    ) {
      selection.setState({ idx: props.idx });
    }
  });

  return (
    <LazyMotion features={domAnimation} strict>
      <div className=" p-5 py-3 border rounded-lg" ref={ref}>
        <m.h3
          ref={headingRef}
          className={cs(
            "text-base mb-4",
            props.idx == selection().idx ? "font-semibold" : "font-normal"
          )}
        >
          {props.label}
        </m.h3>

        <m.div
          key="content"
          // initial={false}
          animate={{ height: selection().idx == props.idx ? "auto" : "0" }}
          className={cs("relative overflow-hidden")}
        >
          <m.div className=" ">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ea saepe
            similique incidunt exercitationem illum, dolorem quidem reiciendis
            dolores quod id! Magni rem voluptatibus possimus facilis eum natus
            ducimus autem ipsum. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Odio nulla tenetur quibusdam! Porro modi,
            pariatur, soluta eum, at dolorum adipisci facere libero repellat
            obcaecati dicta omnis rerum numquam labore aut.
          </m.div>
        </m.div>
      </div>
    </LazyMotion>
  );
});

Accortion.displayName = "Accortion";

export default function TestPage() {
  const accordianRefs = useRef<Record<string, HTMLDivElement | null>>({});
  const [accordianHeights, setAccordianHeights] = useState<
    Record<string, number | null>
  >({});

  const getRefHandler = (index: number) => (el: HTMLDivElement | null) => {
    accordianRefs.current[index] = el;
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setAccordianHeights(
      Object.keys(accordianRefs.current).reduce<Record<string, number | null>>(
        (prevHeight, currentKey) => {
          const currentElement = accordianRefs?.current[currentKey];
          return { ...prevHeight, [currentKey]: currentElement!.offsetHeight };
        },
        {}
      )
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto max-w-lg px-7">
      <div className="h-[500px] flex items-center text-slate-500 font-mono justify-center w-full">
        <span>extra spacing on top, scroll down</span>
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-6">
        <Accortion
          ref={getRefHandler(0)}
          prevAccordianHeight={0}
          label="Accordion #0"
          idx={0}
        ></Accortion>
        <Accortion
          ref={getRefHandler(1)}
          prevAccordianHeight={accordianHeights[0]}
          label="Accordion #1"
          idx={1}
        ></Accortion>
        <Accortion
          ref={getRefHandler(2)}
          prevAccordianHeight={accordianHeights[1]}
          label="Accordion #2"
          idx={2}
        ></Accortion>
        <Accortion
          ref={getRefHandler(3)}
          prevAccordianHeight={accordianHeights[2]}
          label="Accordion #3"
          idx={3}
        ></Accortion>
        <Accortion
          ref={getRefHandler(4)}
          prevAccordianHeight={accordianHeights[3]}
          label="Accordion #4"
          idx={4}
        ></Accortion>
        <Accortion
          ref={getRefHandler(5)}
          prevAccordianHeight={accordianHeights[4]}
          label="Accordion #5"
          idx={5}
        ></Accortion>
        <Accortion
          ref={getRefHandler(6)}
          prevAccordianHeight={accordianHeights[5]}
          label="Accordion #6"
          idx={6}
        ></Accortion>
      </div>

      {/* extra space on bottom */}
      <div className="h-[700px] flex items-center text-slate-500 font-mono justify-center w-full">
        <span>extra spacing on bottom, scroll up</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will use the header but also correct for the previous accordians height, which means when it opens the header remains always in line with center after expanding.

Comment: Ah I think I need to make modifications to this so scrolling up works properly by also taking into account the same logic but in reverse.

Comment: ineteresting. I made a version 2 which reveals an element based on proximity, whichever element closet to center (0.5, i set 0.4). Which solves the issue: fast scrolling or clicking on the scrollbar doesnt work sometimes if element isnt in my provided radius. Its in the codesandbox https://13oy2z-3000.preview.csb.app/version2


I'll try to integrate that with your solution

Comment: That makes sense and works well. Yeh if you integrate the offsets, you can get it so when it opens it opens in the center. However, you have to breakout of using the progress event sadly and do the math yourself in the basic scroll event because you cant add the offset onto the percentage. Well, to be fair, you could probably use the percentage and multiple it by screen height, add the offset, and work back to the percentage again. That would work and i hindsight, its an easier way of doing it.

Comment: I have one question: how would you do this without the use of zustand? I would prefer to avoid it, but when trying not to use it, I find myself that the animation 'opens' but doesn't close. So I guess it's because I am not handling well the state. Do you have any recommendation / suggestion? Thanks!